Find all spanning trees using BFS
While trying to find all spanning trees using the queue, I came to the conclusion that it would be logical to search edges. If there is no new edge in the tree, I add the edge to the tree and put the tree into the queue. I can check if there was an edge in the tree, I can determine if there is a cycle, but I can't figure out how to determine which trees are copies (I could consider the edges in different order, but the tree structure itself will remain the same, and I can't throw out extra trees). There were a few comments on the code, so I tried to rework it. At this point, I used the built-in queue class. However, using containers is a challenge for me at this stage
bool IsAcyclic(int v, const vector<vector<int>>& adj, vector<bool>& visited, int parent) {
    visited[v] = true;
    for (int u : adj[v]) {
        if (!visited[u]) {
            if (!IsAcyclic(u, adj, visited, v))
                return false;
        }
        else if (u != parent) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void findAllSPanningTrees(int start, const vector<vector<int>>& adj, int V) {
    queue<vector<Edge>> q;
    vector<Edge> initial;
    q.push(initial);

    while (!q.empty()) {
        vector<Edge>currentTree = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (currentTree.size() == V - 1) {
            vector<vector<int>> tempAdj(V);
            for (const Edge& edge : currentTree) {
                tempAdj[edge.u].push_back(edge.v);
                tempAdj[edge.v].push_back(edge.u);
            }
            vector<bool> visited(V, false);
            if (IsAcyclic(start, tempAdj, visited, -1))
//I think it was possible to avoid recursion, but I'm actually wondering if I can somehow check for cyclicity previously
                printSpanningTree(currentTree);
        
            continue;
        }
        set<pair<int, int>>usedEdges;
        for (const Edge& edge : currentTree) {
            usedEdges.insert({ min(edge.u,edge.v),max(edge.u,edge.v) });//Since edge (1, 2) and (2, 1) are the same, I keep them as (1, 2)
        }
        for (int u = 0; u < V; u++) {
            for (int v : adj[u]) {
                if (u < v && usedEdges.find({ u,v }) == usedEdges.end()) { //avoiding repeated edges in a tree
                    vector<Edge> newTree = currentTree;
                    newTree.push_back(Edge(u, v));
                    q.push(newTree);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}


Whatever source you're using to learn C++, it's not doing a good job. You do several bad things in your code, but the worst is that you explicitly call the myq destructor, closely followed by a memory leak, and explicit dynamic memory allocation and initialization when none is needed. Oh, and making your own queue class. And using pointers instead of standard containers in general. And probably much more.

I'm glad people are responding to my question and suggesting changes and I will take them into consideration, however my assignment was to develop a queue class and apply it to find all spanning trees of the graph using bfs (or at least realize that I can't do it with a queue). In other words, the algorithmic component. Which is my question

void BFS(int** g, int n, int u, int ** st){ bool* visited = new bool[n]; Seems somebody has been failing to teach you C++. I see no tree class, and visited should be a std::vector<bool>. In current C++ it is very rare to see owning raw pointers, and double pointers are almost unheard of. And manually calling myq.~Queue() should not have been taught to you at all. I would expect something like  along the line of std::vector<TreeView> BFS(const Node& root);

And please show your teacher this : C++ core guidelines and [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk). Because in industry coding in "C" style is considered dangerous and each time we have to unlearn these "C" habits before people become productive. A good teacher should be able to adapt the training material to match these guidelines. E.g. making a Tree class is a wonderful good topic for a datastructures/algorithm class.

" In other words, the algorithmic component. "  If you do not want comments about your programming then you  probably shouldn't post questions on a "question-and-answer website for computer programmers"

I am using a queue template class I wrote -- How are we to know if your queue class does not have bugs?  Here is a suggestion -- write your code to find the spanning trees using std::queue.  If the code works with std::queue, then try to use your home-made queue class.  Right now, you have multiple points of failure, both pointed out by the code you did post, and the code you didn't post (the queue class).  If you had used std::queue and still had the issue of not finding all the spanning trees, then at least we have something concrete to work with, instead of having to guess.
